# Buttons on Bottom navigation bar are not on their position

Tags: android, android-layout, bottomnavigationview

I'm trying to create a bottom navigation bar but the buttons are moving to the right

[image]

how can fix the view in the bottom navigation bar to look like this?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to [so]! You should paste in the code (or xml) you used to define the menu-bar. Be sure to use the code button to format it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need like that one, You need set ShiftMode following like :

```
public static void disableShiftMode(BottomNavigationView view) {
    BottomNavigationMenuView menuView = (BottomNavigationMenuView) view.getChildAt(0);
    try {
        Field shiftingMode = menuView.getClass().getDeclaredField("mShiftingMode");
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(true);
        shiftingMode.setBoolean(menuView, false);
        shiftingMode.setAccessible(false);

    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to get shift mode field", e);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.e("BNVHelper", "Unable to change value of shift mode", e);
    }
}
```

And send your Buttom NavigationView :

```
        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        disableShiftMode(bottomNavigationView);
```

That's all Thank you.